# Django/RestFramework: how to get data from model that has on foreign key in it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models as

```
class Shops(models.Model):
    shopkeeper = models.ForeignKey(Shopkeeper, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    contactNumber = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and

```
class Product(models.Model):
    productsubcategory = models.ForeignKey(ProductSubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shops, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.FileField(null=True)
    detail = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have made serializer class for **product model**. And I want to write a View which should return products of a specific shop. My view is as follow,

```
class ShopkeeperProductAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get(self,request,shop_id):
        products = Product.objects.get(shop=shop_id)
        products_serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(products_serializer.data)
```

and my url is as follow,

```
path('shops/products/<int:shop_id>', views.ShopkeeperProductAPIView.as_view())
```

Please help me out.

Comment: remove `many=True`, should work if you have written correct serializer

Comment: @NageshDhope this will work only if there is only one product in shop. He needs to get all products from specific shop.

Comment: @Bulva, Oops, I my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use:

```
products = Product.objects.get(shop=shop_id)
```

It will return only one product because you used `get()` method. You have to used `filter()` and `many=True` in serializer.

So the code will look like:

```
class ShopkeeperProductAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get(self,request,shop_id):
        products = Product.objects.filter(shop=shop_id)
        products_serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(products_serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why, from all tools that DRF provides, you are using only serializers? Here's how I would created products endpoint. In `viewsets.py`:

```
class ShopkeeperProductViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(shop=pk)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And in `urls.py`:

```
shops_router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'products', ShopkeeperProductViewSet, base_name='product')
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url(r'^shops/', include(shops_router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: I did not read about this procedure. But thanks for pointing out. It made my many jobs very simple :)